Usage of adjust_text in conjunction with plotnine
I'm currently making a plot in Python using plotnine, and wanted to add text labels to it. To avoid too much overlapping, I decided to use adjust_text alongside geom_text. However, adjust_text does not work, and the program is unable to compile.
I first saw this thread, which advised me to include a dictionary and install the adjustText package. Upon doing both, however, I now get this error:
AttributeError: FancyArrowPatch.set() got an unexpected keyword argument 'expand_points'
My relevant code is as follows:
adjust_text_dict = {
    'expand_points': (2,2),
    'arrowprops': {
        'arrowstyle': '-',
        'color': 'black'
    }
}
plot = (p9.ggplot(df, p9.aes("x", "y", label = 'name')) +
        p9.geom_point(shape = "D", color = "#666799", fill = "#4f82be", size = 4) +
        p9.ggtitle('Title') +
        p9.xlab("x") +
        p9.ylab("y") +
        p9.geom_smooth(method = 'lm', se = False) +
        p9.geom_label(adjust_text = adjust_text_dict)
        )


Make sure you have the latest version of plotnine. In a recent version of AdjustText, the API changed somewhat, so an older plotnine may be using a broken API.

I installed both packages on the day this  thread was opened (new Python user), so I'd be surprised if that was the issue.

The newer version of adjustText does not accept the expand_points parameter.
